# Непонятно возвращаемое значение None в самовызываемой функции

Tags: python-3.x

Здравия! Простите, я новичок. Не могу понять, почему в конечном принте, при вызове функции, когда не соблюдается условие if, возвращается None.
Можно ли как то эту абракадабру написать красиво и лаконично?

```
import random, string

k=5

def gen_pasw():
    passw1 = ''.join(random.sample('123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc'
                                          'vbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM', k))
    print(passw1, 'before if')
    if (set(passw1)&set(string.ascii_uppercase) and
        set(passw1)&set(string.digits) and
        set(passw1)&set(string.ascii_lowercase)):
            print(passw1, 'is good in if')
            return passw1
    else:
        print('no good, else')
        gen_pasw()


print(gen_pasw(), 'print at end')


glHUb before if
no good, else
ZkfSN before if
no good, else
dqBHj before if
no good, else
ZOl7S before if
ZOl7S is good in if
None print at end
```

Comment: Потому что в ветке else вы ничего не возвращаете.

Comment: т.е. не смотря на то, что потом происходит вызов функции самой из себя и в итоге вроде бы как стоит return при выполнении условия, и на конечном этапе passw1 получает нужное значение, это не влияет на возвращаемое значение? В моем понимании функция должна лишь тогда знакончить свою работу - когда проверит правильность значения и вернет значение. Как понять логику того, что она на else возращает None, но сама потом продолжает работу и выдает "внутри себя" верное значение?

Comment: Операция `return` возвращает в точку вызова. В случае рекурсии возврат происходит в предыдущий вызов функции, а не в первый.